# how to batch create contact with Google peopleservice dotnet library

Tags: google-people-api

The question is in the title.
I'm switching the google contact apis (that are being deprecated) to people api.
I can't find a way to batch the creation of contacts using the dotnet library in c#.

I'm currently using the nugetpackage Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1 version 1.50.0.2252
The library does not contact a batch creation method. However the documentation contains a batch rest api.

```
PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest request = new PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest(_peopleService, contactToCreate);
Person createdContact = request.Execute();
```

I can of course call the rest endpoint directly but I would prefer to go through the dotnet library provided by Google.
Any reason for this endpoint not beoing exposed by the dotnet library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are working on it.

You can find the `BatchCreateContacts` on the latest update from github 
[google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client)

[image: BatchCreateContactsRequest]